# How to block the user for a certain amount of time

Tags: users, cron

Suppose, I am working in X environment, and I want to have an obligatory periodic rest. Is it possible to setup a root cron job, that will block my user for 5 minutes every 45 minutes?

I am using Linux Slackware 14.0.

Comment: What do you mean by block? No keyboard input, no mouse movement? Frozen X?

Comment: @Anthon "No keyboard input, no mouse movement?" - yes. It's the same as frozen X. Or switch to console and block him there.

Comment: Is an application that does this out of the question? There are many productivity type apps that do exactly this.

Comment: @sim "Is an application that does this out of the question?" - no, put it as an answer, please.